# Switch if enabled

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple Switch in my Drawer:

```dart
SwitchListTile(
  title: Text("Dark Theme"),
  value: darkThemeEnabled,
  onChanged: (darkThemeEnabled) {
               if (darkThemeEnabled) {
                  _themeChanger.setTheme(ThemeData.dark());
                } else {
                  _themeChanger.setTheme(AppTheme.light);
                }
)
```

When I enable my Switch it changes to my dark theme, but how can I change it back? How can I run something on disabling?
I know it must be pretty simple, but I'm currently stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SwitchListTile widget itself doesn't manage state. You can create a StatefulWidget and call setState to update the UI.

```
class OnOff extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OnOffState createState() => _OnOffState();
}

class _OnOffState extends State<OnOff> {
  bool flag = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SwitchListTile(
      title: const Text('Change Me'),
      value: flag,
      onChanged: (bool value) {
        setState(() {
          flag = value;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SwitchListTile(
  title: Text("Dark Theme"),
  value: darkThemeEnabled,
  onChanged: (){
    if(darkThemeEnabled)
      doSometing();
  }
)
```

Comment: With this I can run something when it gets enabled, but not if it gets disabled.

Comment: else
      doSometing2();

Comment: make sure to use (setState)
to see change